# Frequency calculation and exploration of other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, frequency

So I am having this "query", on Dataframe x:

```
x.withColumn("person",explode($"col1.col2")).groupBy("person.col3").count().sort(desc("count")).show
```

this calculates frequencies for `col3`, sorts them and prints a table with columns: `col3,count`

I want it also to print a specific column from `x` , together with `col3,count`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Generally, you would set the result set to a new Dataframe, then join it back to `x` and select the desired columns. Probably need to see `x.printSchema` if you want specific help on doing that.

Comment: join on which key, since the key is not preserved when I groupBy ? Thanks for the reply

Comment: That is precisely why I asked for the schema, to try and infer the join key. Can you `.groupBy("key_column", "person.col3")` and still get your desired aggregation?

Comment: Or, if you don't care about the uniqueness of `col3`, just join it back against `person.col3`.

Answer (score 0):

doing a left inner join, and a right inner join [this does not exist, you just reverse the Dataframes] should give the same number of rows for both the 2 joins mentioned and the original dataframe, assuming the key is not always null